# Routine Update has stopped my Nordvpn altogether

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am a new user to Ubuntu.  I installed it on a vpn.  Until now I've been happy with it.  I installed nordvpn through the terminal and it was working fine - until I allowed ubuntu to update itself last night,  Now nordvpn has completely stopped working.  It is saying there are errors in the config file and sometimes it says  check your connection.  The update has completely ruined my vpn.  I tried to uninstall it but it didn't seem to work because I also have openvpn installed and I don't know how to remove that.  I am new from windows and used to gui uninstall processes.